# Use all values in ecdf but apply xlimit

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'd like to plot his data [1] which is heavily skewed with `ecdf`. The code is

```
df <- data.frame(x=eval(parse(file("http://sprunge.us/XYJK"))))
ggplot(df, aes(x=x)) + xlim(0,100) + geom_line(stat='ecdf')
```

As you see, the line goes to 100% at 100, which implies that the data beyond 100 is excluded. Can I include them somehow?

[1] http://sprunge.us/XYJK,

Comment: Please find a way to share your data without using `eval(parse())`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please read `?xlim` and find out that you can do it like this:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=x)) + geom_line(stat='ecdf') + coord_cartesian(xlim = c(0,100))
```